# PHP: ftp_connect - get any error details

Tags: php, ftp, error-logging

I'm trying to connect to the remote server with ftp_connect and it returns false all the time for this particular server.

Is there any way to get details of the error? I tried:

```
error_get_last();
```

also

```
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

But it didn't work. Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP docs it "returns a FTP stream on success or FALSE on error" so false is the correct result for a connection error. Things to look at are port numbers, firewalls that might block the connection, IP address blocking, etc.